# foundation buttons in mobile layout

Tags: .net, button, webforms, zurb-foundation

I have [this CRUD app](http://sqltkt.arielferro.com.ar/adm/), written in .NET Web forms and Foundation Zurb 3
If you check the link on a desktop pc at full size, you can click the button and submit the form.
But if you reduce the size of your Chrome browser to get the mobile layout, the button does nothing at all.
I removed JS validations, checked inside JS files and found no way to get the reason for this behaviour.
Hope you may help me someway.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this thing! It was an issue on my layout. I redesigned that part and Voila! It works now!